# <app name> cannot be installed (Flex mobile for iPad)

Tags: ipad, air, flex4

I am developing mobile application for iPad using Flex/Air.
While I am debugging the application using the Flash Builder Emulator, everything seems to be alright. However when I export a release, using a developer certificate and exporting it as "Ad hoc package for limited distribution" and try to install the release on a device which is registered to use this app, the installer returns error: " cannot be installed".

I was searching for an answer for 3 days, but I couldn't find the problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!
Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be many reasons, probably down to the Apple certificates or provisioning profiles.

Try exporting using your Apple Distribution certificate rather than your Developer certificate.

If that doesn't work I would suggest deleting/revoking all certificates and profiles and start from scratch. Nowadays this should take less that 30 minutes to complete.

Comment: You are right! I have created a new application id + new provisioning profile and now the app is installing as it should!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ivan.

Have you tried building it for Android and installing it on a device? It might be that there is a problem with the installation. At least this will show you if the problem is the installation.

Comment: I just tried it and yes it perfectly works on Android device!